# Including "spring-security-config" into classpath makes spring hang with NoClassDef at "Aware"

Tags: spring, spring-security, noclassdeffounderror

I guess such error is because there are two conflicting jars in classpath. When I put into my pom these lines:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
 <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

it fails, but when i put those

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
```

it works. These is yet another jar where these exclusions must be applied to that is spring-security-web.

Is there any more elegant way to do that? Maybe the problem lies elsewhere and this is only a "hack" or something?

Comment: Ensure that you are consistently using the same version for any artifact with the group org.springframework and the same version for any artifact with the group org.springframework.security. If that does not help, can please post the dependencies displayed when you invoke "mvn dependency:list"? Can you add the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Spring security has a different version scheme with spring core (I believe historically they are maintained by different organization). I suggest you don't use generic `${spring.version}` variable.

Read the documentation of what minimum spring core is required for corresponding spring security version

If you believe you've got all the versioning correct, next possible cause is your maven configuration itself. Often you did not realize you've set your settings to NOT lookup from central repository / your organization internal maven repo (nexus) has a stale index not having latest version of spring artifacts

Comment: I have also used the highest versions available for both artifacts that is 3.1.x for the security and 3.2.3 for everything else... still the same. There has to be a way!

Comment: Updated my answer to include maven settings problem